# Percentile Ranks in Matlab

Tags: correlation, matlab, data-transformation, quantiles, ranks

I have 2 vectors of raw values.  I need to do a percentile rank correlation and an ordinal rank correlation between them in Matlab.

```
Vec1 = [25    28    29    29    31    32    33    33    33    35    37] ;
```

I'm using `corr` function in Matlab with `type=Spearman` for the ordinal part.

I'm confused about the percentile rank part.  Until now I was using `tiedranks*100/length` and would feed the output to `corr` function with `type=Pearson` (courtesy of a forum answer).  However, the correct way is at http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/introbook/sbk14m.htm.

```
Website Ranks    = [4.6  13.6  27.3  27.3  40.9  50    68.2  68.2  68.2  86.4  95.4] ;
TiedRanks*100/len= [9.09 18.18 31.81 31.81 45.45 54.54 72.72 72.72 72.72 90.90 100];
```

Please let me know which is correct? Can I use Matlab's `prctile` function here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentile ranks are defined as the website describes. The formula you were using gives something other quantity which is something like a rescaled rank and it is incorrect if you were trying to get percentile rank.

Also, note that rank is not the same as percentile rank, these are different quantities. Spearman correlation is equivalent to taking the Pearson correlation of the rank.

Comment: Thanks! I had used the link https://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1J7OE3/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-1J7OE3 earlier.  I now see that it dealt with percent ranks (& not percentile!)